# Invoke Action Method with a parameter within same controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult Faced(Vira model)
{
    HomeIndex helper = new HomeIndex();
    ...
}
```

Action Method above will be invoked within:

```
public ActionResult BackToEmp()
{
    ..
    Vira vr = new Vira();
    Vira.Email="abc@abc.com";
    Vira.Password="123456";
    return RedirectToAction("Faced");
}
```

model parameter the method Faced has, is of class Vira:

```
public class Vira{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I need to pass the Vira object to method Faced. I thought RedirectToAction should be OK. But didn't figure out how to send it? What's the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you should be able to do:

```
return this.Faced(vr);
```

However if you want to make sure the user's url changes ... you'll have to make the parameters simpler:

```
public ActionResult Faced(string email, string password)
{
    HomeIndex helper = new HomeIndex();
...
}
public ActionResult BackToEmp()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Faced", new { email = "abc@abc.com", password = "123456" });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a overload of the `RedirectToAction`:

```
  public ActionResult BackToEmp()
  {
    ...
   Vira vr = new Vira();
    vr.Email="abc@abc.com";
    vr.Password="123456";
    return RedirectToAction("Faced", new {model =vr});
 }
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: This won't work because it's a complex object correct?  Instead he would have to pass the strings separately.

Answer (score 1):

Inanikian's answer will get the job done, however if I may make a recommendation, it would be easier to read if you constructed each instance of the Vira class with the information it needs instead of adding it in retrospect.  For example you can add a two parameter constructor as follows:

```
public class Vira {
    public string Email { get; private set; }
    public string Password { get; private set; }
    public Vira (string email, string password) {
        this.Email = email
        this.Password = password
    }
}
```

Then your controller action would remain light:

```
public ActionResult BackToEmp()
{
     return RedirectToAction("Faced", new Vira("abc@abc.com", "123456"));
}
```